# Unknown provider - $locationProvider from ui.router.router

Tags: angularjs, location-provider

var mysite = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router','ui.bootstrap']);

mysite.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider ) {

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/portfolio');

$stateProvider

    // HOME STATES AND NESTED VIEWS ========================================
    .state('portfolio', {
        url: '/portfolio',
        templateUrl: 'portfolio/portfolio.html',
        controller: 'MainController'

    })
    .state('about', {
        url: '/about',
        templateUrl: 'about/about.html',
        controller: 'MainController'

    })
    .state('contact', {
        url: '/contact',
        templateUrl: 'contact/contact.html',
        controller: 'MainController'

    })
```

});

I am getting Unknown provider: $locationProvider from ui.router.router  error while running the page .

Please help if i am missing something in the code .

Answer (score 0):

use

```
mysite.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider)
```

instead of

```
mysite.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider )
```